# R ligação entre tabelas por data.frame

Tags: r, data.frame

Olá! Tenho duas tabelas no banco e elas estão ligadas por uma FK, como eu crio um terceiro data.frame com os dados de ambas as tabelas ligadas pelo FK.

Ou seja, eu tenho:

```
dataframe1 <- tbl(con, "TabelaLegado1")
dataframe1 <- as_tibble(dataframe1  %>% select(id, nome))

dataframe2 <- tbl(con, "TabelaLegado2")
dataframe2 <- as_tibble(dataframe2  %>% select(id, texto, id_tabela_legado1))
```

Preciso pegar o "nome" da TabelaLegado1 e o id, texto da TabelaLegado2, em uma TabelaLegado3, e que essas duas tabelas estejam ligadas pelo id da TabelaLegado1, e o id_tabela_legado1 da TabelaLegado2 para trazer os dados certos para essa terceira tabela.

Comment: Pode ser com R base `help('merge')` ou com `help('dplyr::left_join')` (ou `inner_join`, `right_join`, etc). É difícil dizer sem ver os dados.

Comment: Muito obrigado!